# substring not found (trying to use YouTube API)

Tags: api, youtube, enter

path = "D:\Data Analyst - YouTube\video\Marcelle Video"

api_key = "MY API"

youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

youtube_url = input("Enter Youtube URL: ")

video_id = youtube_url[youtube_url.index("?v=") + 3:]

I got this error:

Enter Youtube URL: https://youtu.be/W3CoM_xkn9E
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Data Analyst - YouTube\video\video.py", line 14, in 
video_id = youtube_url[youtube_url.index("?v=") + 3:]
ValueError: substring not found
PS C:\Users\UTENTE>

Can you guys help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that the URL has the **`?v=`** characters.

If it has it, use your current code.

Otherwise, modify your code as follows:

```
# This is the URL: 
youtube_url = "https://youtu.be/W3CoM_xkn9E"

# Separate the elements by "/" character: 
myArray = youtube_url.split("/")

# Get the latest element in the array: 
video_id = myArray[-1]

# Print the result:
print("video_id: " + video_id)
```

Result:

```
video_id: W3CoM_xkn9E
```

Execute this code here at [mycompiler.io](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/K3LKOWyPAWE).

---

***N.B:*** YouTube links vary in its presentation, so, you have to check how to handle the video_url (*i.e. **`youtube_url`***).